# How to allow SSH session to linux server but, do not allow SFTP file transfer?

Tags: ssh, sftp

We allow SSH access to admins along with SFTP file transfer access using PAM. Now unique case is to grant SSH session to one particular user to read/write/execute files but do not allow transfer file to/from own machine to linux.

I understand SSH and SFTP both use port 22. technically, SFTP is build on SSH seems not possible.
still any leads?

Comment: Is there some reason you care about SFTP in particular? If the user can both access files and run commands - even basic shell commands - they can use the SSH session to do anything that SFTP can do. It might be a little more awkward, but it's not _hard_. For example, `ssh -tq user@host cat path/to/remote/file >> path/to/local/file` will connect to the remote host and read a remote file through the SSH tunnel back to your machine where it will be written to a local file; this is nearly identical to using SFTP to copy (get) the remote file to the local machine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP wants impossible things. The only way you can probably resolve this issue: change the user shell to something utterly restricted and then disable the SFTP subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered in detail [in this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/28858/is-it-possible-to-prevent-scp-while-still-allowing-ssh-access).  The quick answer is no, you cannot disallow SFTP and still allow SSH.  There are still some options to curtail what a user can do.

### Limit the SSH commands a user can run.

Editing the `authorized_keys` file one can make a list of commands the user is able to run.  [See this post for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346081/restrict-list-of-commands-over-ssh).

### Setup a user to have no write permissions

The user won't be able to send anything that is saved to the server, but they can still read data and execute commands.  A user doesn't need to have write access to their home directory, or any other directory.  Could get complected if the commands they need to run create temporary files.